# CSS animation onclick and reverse next onclick

Tags: css, css-animations

I am using a spritesheet and keyframes to animate the image on a button when it is clicked.

When the button is clicked I want the frames to run in one direction and leave the button on the last image in the spritesheet, and when it is clicked again I want the same frames to run backwards, leaving the button on the first image on the spritesheet.

I am currently trying to use jquery to change the class on the button to an animating class when it is clicked, but this doesn't seem to be working.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/10295/

JS:

```
function animate(){
    $('.hi').addClass('animate-hi');
}
```

CSS:

```
.hi {
width: 50px;
height: 72px;
background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
}

.animate-hi {
    animation: play 2s steps(10);
}

@keyframes play {
   from { background-position:    0px; }
     to { background-position: -500px; }
}
```

Comment: You need to include the webkits for different browsers.

Comment: I messed around with your code, and made something of my own. http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/10301/

Comment: Yeah, I know, left those out for simplicity for the fiddle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are using an animation-capable browser. For me this works in Firefox.

The following might be just what you wanted:

http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/10299/

Code:

```js
function animateButton() {
  var button = $('.hi');
  if (button.hasClass('animate-hi')) {
    button.removeClass('animate-hi').addClass('animate-hi-reverse');
  } else if (button.hasClass('animate-hi-reverse')) {
    button.removeClass('animate-hi-reverse').addClass('animate-hi');
  } else {
    button.addClass('animate-hi');
  }
};
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.hi').on("click", function() {
    animateButton();
  });
});
```

```css
.hi {
  width: 50px;
  height: 72px;
  background-image: url("http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png");
}

.animate-hi {
  animation: play 2s steps(10);
}

.animate-hi-reverse {
  animation: play-reverse 2s steps(10);
}

@keyframes play {
  from {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: -500px;
  }
}

@keyframes play-reverse {
  from {
    background-position: -500px;
  }
  to {
    background-position: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="http://s.cdpn.io/79/sprite-steps.png" />
<button class="hi" type="button"></button>
```

Comment: That's great, thanks. As I mentioned that I wanted the end image after the first click to be the last image on the spritesheet I've edited your fiddle to add that in as well in case anyone else wants it: http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/10300/

Answer (score 0):

Make a counter variable which checks if the button is clicked or not.
And based on the counter value add class to the element for example:

```
 var counter=0;
 $('.btn').on('click',function(){
  if(counter=0)
   {
     $('.hi').addClass('animate-hi');
     counter = 1;
   }
  else
   {
        counter = 0;
       $('.hi').removeClass('animate-hi');
   }
 });
```

Make sure to declare the counter variable outside the function. Else every time its value initialized to 0.

Comment: I've tried this here: http://jsfiddle.net/CGmCe/10298/ but adding the class isn't working to trigger the animation.