# CSS Transitions with multiple delays

Tags: html, css

So I am using CSS transitions to have multiple blocks come together and form a new image (a house in this case). Thing is, I am using delay on each of the blocks so they start coming in at different times. That is all working fine.

Now, what I would like to have happen is when I click a different button those blocks need to be sent back to their original positions and in reverse order of which they appeared.

```
.house-container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.house-block {
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff
}
.roof {
  position: absolute;
  top: -228px;
  transition: top .5s ease 2.5s
}
.roof.moved {
  top: 0
}
.peak {
  position: absolute;
  top: -145px;
  right: 76px;
  transition: top .5s ease 2.0s
}
.peak.moved {
  top: 47px
}
.peak:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.top-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -165px;
  top: 194px;
  transition: left .5s ease 1.2s;
}
.top-left.moved {
  left: 103px
}
.top-left:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.top-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 257px;
  top: -170px;
  transition: top .5s ease 1.6s
}
.top-center.moved {
  top: 194px;
  left: 257px
}
.top-center:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.top-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 640px;
  top: 194px;
  transition: left .5s ease 0.9s
}
.top-right.moved {
  top: 194px;
  left: 442px
}
.top-right:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.bottom-left {
  position: absolute;
  left: -165px;
  top: 392px;
  transition: left .5s ease 0.3s
}
.bottom-left.moved {
  left: 103px;
  top: 392px
}
.bottom-left:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.bottom-right {
  position: absolute;
  left: 660px;
  top: 467px;
  transition: left .5s ease 0.1s
}
.bottom-right.moved {
  top: 467px;
  left: 257px
}
.bottom-right:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.middle-center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 257px;
  top: -120px;
  transition: top .5s ease 0.6s
}
.middle-center.moved {
  top: 355px;
  left: 257px
}
.middle-center:hover {
  transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
  z-index: 99
}
.house-block .energy-mngt {
  position: absolute;
  width: 464px;
  top: 20%
}
.house-block .water-conver {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 20%
}
.house-block .solar {
  position: absolute;
  width: 181px;
  top: 20%
}
.house-block .leed-certfd {
  position: absolute;
  width: 123px;
  top: 30%
}
.house-block .multimedia {
  position: absolute;
  width: 181px;
  top: 30%
}
.house-block .security {
  position: absolute;
  width: 150px;
  top: 25%
}
.house-block .auto-cont-integri {
  position: absolute;
  width: 308px;
  top: 10%
}
.house-block h4 {
  display: block;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin-bottom: 0
}
.house-block .solar h4, .house-block .multimedia h4, .house-block .auto-cont-integri h4 {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 20px
}
```

As you can see above, the `.roof` is the last element to appear (`2.5` second delay) and the `.bottom-right` block is the first (`.1s` delay). I want these same delays to happen in the reverse order when being hidden (removing the `.moved` class from the elements).

Is this even possible?

Thanks

Comment: I think what you need to look at are CSS keyframes https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/ there's a few other examples such as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962653/css-animation-onclick-and-reverse-next-onclick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure it's possible, just add the forward delay to your "visible" state and the backwards delay to your normal state. Or if you have a "hidden" state the other way arround:

```
.my-element.-isVisible {
  ...
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.my-element {
  ...
  transition-delay: 2.5s;
}
```

This will add a 1s delay when the elements becomes "visible" and a 2.5s delay if it becomes "hidden" again.